# Does shaka Packager support TS output?

Tags: http-live-streaming, drm, widevine, shaka

I am trying to use shaka packager to encrypt videos, we want to use hls, I know shaka packager supports MP4 format ouput,  but I am not sure whether shaka packager support TS format output or not. If supported , how to specify parameters while writing shaka packager commands?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does support TS streams as part of HLS packaging.

They provide some examples under the HLS section of the documentation (https://google.github.io/shaka-packager/html/tutorials/hls.html):

[image]

Comment: It works. But I got another question, What's the lowest version of hls Widevine supports ?the version of Shaka packager hls output is Version 6, I just want to make sure the playback on the browers of Andorid, Is it possible for Shaka packager to output version 3 of hls ? And Does Shaka packager support AES-128 ? I have too many questions, thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: I think you might be better looking at the Shaka GitHub list for this level of detail - there is a comment there that AES-128 is not supported at present for instance. As a side note, most video stream using DASH to Android devices - I am guessing you know this and for your case need HLS, but mentioning it just in case.

Answer (score 0):

In most of cases it is possible to play HLS in browser on Android devices, but you can face problems with performance or battery usage because of manifest parsing in JS. I will recommend you to use DASH for Android devices if it possible.